# Error "is not an enclosing class" while Implement Firebase Auth in a Login Activity Android Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an android app that I created using the Login Activity Template (New Project -> Login Activity -> Java, API 26), which created a scaffold with the data and ui.login packages. I'm trying to implement Firebase auth with email & password.

Following the docs and also understanding the function of each class, I started touching the class LoginDataSource (from data package) and adding the following code:

```
public class LoginDataSource {

private static final String TAG = "EmailPassword";

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

public Result<LoggedInUser> login(String username, String password) {

    // Initialize Firebase Auth
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    try {
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(username, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                            //FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            //updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                            //Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //updateUI(null);
                        }
                    }
                });
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        Log.d(TAG,"user display name: " + user.getDisplayName());
        LoggedInUser appUser = new LoggedInUser( user.getUid(), user.getDisplayName());
        return new Result.Success<>(appUser);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new Result.Error(new IOException("Error logging in", e));
    }
```

As I understand, the addOnCompleteListener expects my activity, which lives in the ui.login package, so when I try to use it, I get the error:

```
'com.example.appname.ui.login.LoginActivity' is not an enclosing class
```

When I use the `this` keyword, I get the error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'addOnCompleteListener(com.samuelkb.aipuzzles.data.LoginDataSource, anonymous com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener<com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult>)'
```

It makes sense to keep the logic in my data package and not in my UI package.
I'm unsure how I should implement Firebase in my app, so any guidance is welcome.

Comment: Have you tried to use `getApplicationContext()` instead?

Comment: @AlexMamo I sent the activity as a method param from the UI package to the data package, and it worked well, the only remaining issue I have is when the task fails I can't send the error to inform the login wasn't completed.

Comment: Maybe this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336) will help.

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks! It is really useful.
Even though I have been able to run my app, I noticed that the on-complete call is async, and the Login Activity Template is not structured for that behaviour

Comment: In that case, you should structure it that way.